# What is the official Perl documentation on the web?

Tags: perl, perldoc

I found [perldoc.pl](https://perldoc.pl/) with a high usability level being up-to-date to version 5.30.0.

[Perl.org](https://www.perl.org/) links to [perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org/) which stops at version 5.26.1. But on the other hand, it links to *Download* (version 5.28.2) to *Strawberry Perl* (actually version 5.30.0) which I find very confusing.

I already know that Perl 6 is a completely different language. Is there maybe another language barrier after 5.26.*?

### Background

Since I use it rarely, a program update is the starting point when I reenter Perl. And that's why I was interested in studying the [delta documentation](https://perldoc.pl/perl5300delta) *before* installing, and this delta was hard to find.

Comment: The most recent stable Perl 5 version is 5.30.

Comment: @simbabque thanks for the feedback. So the issue seems to be just a lack of time to update the official one? But if the [Perldoc Browser](https://github.com/Grinnz/perldoc-browser) generates the web view from the documentation installed with Perl, couldn't it be an option for the perldoc.perl.org maintainers to switch to it?

Comment: @Wolf: Every page on [perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org/) contains the email address of the site owner. Perhaps he would be grateful if you were to email him and offer to help him maintain the site.

Comment: The current state of perldoc.perl.org is indeed an appearance problem. Imagine if the PHP official documentation did not show the latest version of their docs. From outside it is assumed that a language's official docs will be from their latest version. perl.org also needs to be updated to reference 5.30 as the latest version, but I will send a pull request for this (this is maintained instead by the NOC at https://github.com/perlorg/perlweb).

Comment: To answer the actual question, there is nothing special about 5.28 or 5.30 (which just came out)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The site at [perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org) is the "official" one (you can tell as it's on the perl.org domain), but that site is run by someone outside of the Perl Foundation and it seems that they have been too busy to update the site recently. I believe that [perldoc.pl](https://perldoc.pl) is an alternative project that was set up when it was noticed that the older site was no longer being kept up to date.

Actually, you can always get the most up-to-date and official documents on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/release/perl).

Comment: I see: CPAN also has a delta for perl v5.30.0 but not an own URL for it.

Comment: @Wolf: The delta for the current version of Perl is always just called "perldelta". Once Perl 5.30.1 is released, the current perldelta will be renamed perl5300delta.

Comment: ... the official docs are less usable, compare https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perldiag.pod#Variable-%22%s%22-will-not-stay-shared vs. https://perldoc.pl/perldiag#Variable-%22%25s%22-will-not-stay-shared vs. https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Variable-%22%25s%22-will-not-stay-shared

Comment: *The delta for the current version [...]* -- this is just what I wanted to say, *perldelta* currently leads to 5.28.2 (on CPAN)

Comment: @Wolf: Oh, you're right. But that's because [https://metacpan.org/release/perl](https://metacpan.org/release/perl) is pointing to 5.28.2, not 5.30.0. Not sure why that is. I'll find someone to report it to.

Comment: Great, thanks you'll have a look on it. Such things are hard for occasional users of Perl.

Comment: @Wolf: I reported it to the #metacpan channel on irc.perl.org and it's now fixed.

Comment: While MetaCPAN is a great resource for CPAN docs, it's not ideal for core docs. It displays docs as they are present in CPAN tarballs, and several cases of core perldocs are generated on install, such as [perlapi](https://perldoc.pl/perlapi) and the [current version perlXXXdelta](https://perldoc.pl/perl5300delta) which is nicer for future linkability. It is also nice to have individual function pages and tailored core doc search functions. These are the reasons I found metacpan insufficient for this purpose and followed the perldoc.perl.org approach to create perldoc.pl.

Comment: You are correct on the motivation: perldoc.perl.org has become completely unmaintained, with many [unfixed issues](https://github.com/jonallen/perldoc.perl.org/issues) and only a brief update to install new perl versions every couple years (which also seems to have stopped since 5.26.1). Despite offers to help there has been no response. Based on the [mojolicious docs](https://mojolicious.org) I created a new site that would be easy to fix or avoid these open issues and maintain in the future.

Comment: @Grinnz: Have you considered approaching the Perl NOC team and asking for perldoc.perl.org being repointed at your site?

Comment: @DaveCross I attempted to open a dialog about the state of the site which would be a precursor to any such suggestion but got no response unfortunately.